# How to programmatically pass options to Babel transforms/plugins?

Tags: javascript, node.js, babeljs, strict

A tool I work on uses Babel programmatically. It requires few plugins and everything works fine.

Tho, I want to pass options to a Babel transform. I realized I didn't did that yet, and looks like what I'm trying just doesn't work.

Specifically, I want to include the [`babel-transform-strict-mode`](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-strict-mode/) and pass `strict:false` to disable the global strict mode.

The docs explain how to use it when having a `.babelrc` file:

```
// with options
{
  "plugins": [
    ["transform-strict-mode", {
      "strict": true
    }]
  ]
}
```

In my code I have:

```
const babelify = require("babelify")
    , es2015 = require("babel-preset-es2015")
    , reactify = require("babel-preset-react")
    , strictMode = require("babel-plugin-transform-strict-mode")
    ;

...

this.browserify.transform(babelify, {
    global: true,
    babelrc: false,
    presets: [
        reactify
      , es2015
      , [
            strictMode
          , { strict: false }
        ]
    ] 
});
```

While `es2015` and `reactify` work great in the `presets` array, adding `strictMode` with `{ strict: false }` just doesn't work.

The error is:

```
ReferenceError: [BABEL] /home/.../index.js: Unknown option: foreign.visitor.
Check out http://babeljs.io/docs/usage/options/ for more
information about options.

A common cause of this error is the presence of a
configuration options object without the corresponding
preset name. Example:

Invalid:
  `{ presets: [{option: value}] }`
Valid:
  `{ presets: [['presetName', {option: value}]] }`

For more detailed information on preset configuration,
please see
http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/#pluginpresets-options.
```

If I use instead of `strictMode` the transform name (`["transform-strict-mode", { strict: false }]`), it won't find the module, obviously, because this is part of a different module.

How can I pass options to the `require`d modules (in this case the `strictMode`), programmatically (without `babelrc`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally the recommended approach here is to disable ES6 module support, since ES6 modules are auto-strict. e.g.

```
this.browserify.transform(babelify, {
  sourceType: 'script',
  presets: [
    reactify,
    [es2015, {modules: false}],
  ],
})
```

In your specific case, since your issue is breaking things in `node_modules`, this is because of your usage of `global: true`.

I'm assuming that you specifically are passing `global: true` because you have `node_modules` that container ES6? If so, you should whitelist the things you compile by specifying an `ignore` regex for `babelify` like:

```
// ...
global: true,
ignore: /node_modules\/(?:some_es6_module|some_other_es6_module)/,
// ...
```

to ignore any file with `node_modules` in the path, except modules named `some_es6_module` and `some_other_es6_module`. That way things like `underscore` will not be affected.

Comment: Ah, that's interesting. So, does that mean that I won't be able to `import foo from "foo"` anymore? I ended by using [this plugin](https://github.com/genify/babel-plugin-transform-remove-strict-mode) which probably what it does it just removes the `"use strict";` kinda everywhere. Thanks!

Comment: That's an option, just keep in mind that your code is no longer spec compliant, so if you want to use ES6 modules once they land in Node, it will run into this problem again and have no way to fix it without using CommonJS.

Comment: I simply had some issues using some libraries (e.g. `underscore`) on the client side, because they were checking `if (this._) {...}` but `this` was `undefined`, therefore it was failing.

Comment: Ah I missed that you were using `global: true` to also compile `node_modules`. I've updated the answer.

Comment: If trying to copy/paste this into a `.babelrc`, you'll need format to JSON with double quotes around keys and string values. I suggest updating the example above to eliminate having to modify the copy/paste .

Comment: @PaulBarry This question is specifically about how to pass options _programmatically_ since the user has loaded the plugins via `require`, so it isn't meant to be used in a `.babelrc`. I edited to make that clearer though.

Answer (score 0):

babel-plugin-transform-strict-mode is a plugin not a preset component,so you must set plugin in plugins option.

```
this.browserify.transform(babelify, {
global: true,
babelrc: false,
presets: [
    reactify
  , es2015
],
plugins:[
  [
        strictMode
      , { strict: false }
    ]
]
```

});